# Global MySQL query in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, global

In an attempt to try and narrow my query down, I'm still very new to Codeigniter framework...

I want to define global variables (eg. in autoloaded helpers) and use global mysql queries throughout my site - but I don't understand how to do the latter (global mysql queries).

I understand the concept of defining single variables in a helper... and I understand the concept of creating a single mysql query in a model, loading it in a controller and using it in a view file (with a foreach loop).

How (and where) do I create a mysql query that can be autoloaded (or whatever) and used anywhere on my site - without the need to load it in every controller?

Comment: You don't run queries in the views. I hope you understand how MVC works, otherwise read [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html). You create that in a controller if you are using active queries or in model if you don't. The result is asigned to a variable which is passed to the view file (like [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)).

Comment: @machineaddict, I hope you understand how [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) works, because **codeigniter is not implementing it**.

Comment: I do understand MVC; I don't know where exactly (and how) I create the global query itself (model, helper etc.), and then how I use this in view (foreach loop or whatever etc.) When I google "codeigniter global mysql query" I get a lot of results from other people with far more complex and specific questions than mine - I just want to get my head around the basics - does my question make sense?

Comment: @tereško: you are right, it doesn't necessary imply MVC, but "CodeIgniter is based on the Model-View-Controller development pattern"

Comment: @tereško and the others: I've seen so many times some users that don't understand other users and they just close the question. Please open the question, I have the answer for this guy. I had the same "problem".

Comment: @machineaddict I have edited my question now to hopefully better explain my question. If you understand what I am trying to achieve and know the answer, I'd be very grateful for an input.

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://pastebin.com/azAmBwhj), as probably these guys will not open the question again.

Comment: @user2505513: did you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

this might help.. models would probably be your best bet. below i have given some insite on how to use controlelrs/models/libraries in general, i would put my mysql code into the appropriate model file. and call it via any controller

// Library/profiles.php

```
class My_library 
  {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->CI =& get_instance(); // Existing Code Igniter Instance
    }

    public function my_lib_method()
    {
      // Your Code Here
      // can communicate back with CI by using $this->CI
      // $this->CI->load->view(....);
      // $this->CI->load->model(...);
      // ETC
    }
  }
```

// models/my_model.php

```
class My_model extends CI_Model{

    public function my_mdl_method(){
      // Your Code Here   
    }

  }
```

// controllers/my_controller.php

```
class My_controller extends CI_Controller 
  {
    public function my_ctrl_method(){
      $this->load->library('my_library');
      $this->load->model('my_model');

      // calling a library method
      $this->my_library->my_lib_method();

      // calling a model method
      $this->my_model->my_mdl_method();    
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your `my_lib_method` "should" return the result and in `my_ctrl_method` be assigned to some variable, then passed to the final view. Because the result is usually not "echo"-ed directly. Just an idea...